# Create 5 different random images in PHP

Tags: php, image

I have the following code in a php file to create a random image using php:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$my_img = imagecreate(rand(200,400), rand(50,100));
$background = imagecolorallocate($my_img, 0, 0, rand(1, 255));
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate($my_img, rand(1, 255), rand(1, 255), 0);
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate($my_img, rand(1, 255), rand(1, 255), 0);
imagestring($my_img, 4, 30, 25, "Random Text Here", $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imagepng($my_img);
imagecolordeallocate($line_color);
imagecolordeallocate($text_color);
imagecolordeallocate($background);
imagedestroy($my_img);
```

I add the image using an html file like this:

```
<img src="myphpfile.php">
```

If I do that more than once:

```
<img src="myphpfile.php">
<img src="myphpfile.php">
<img src="myphpfile.php">
<img src="myphpfile.php">
<img src="myphpfile.php">
```

it generates the same image 5 times. How can I use the php file to display a different image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a random query string to prevent the browser from thinking it's the same image and caching it.

```
<img src="myphpfile.php?1">
<img src="myphpfile.php?2">
<img src="myphpfile.php?3">
<img src="myphpfile.php?4">
<img src="myphpfile.php?5">
```

Comment: I like @accurate respondetur's answer better if it works!

Comment: @Samuel, this is better.  Otherwise you are relying on the vagaries of servers and browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The image is being cached. Add no cache headers:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"); header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: If I use this in that php file only, will it affect caching for my entire site?

Comment: No, only for the image.php file. Test it!